# Excel VBA 424 error Object Required, in Cells(row, col).Value

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first VBA Script,  when i rub below code, i got **424** Error on  **Cells(row, col).Value = Val(data(index))** and **Cells(row, col).Value = data(index)**. i am freshman on VBA Script. so how to fix this error.

Thanks Very much.

```
Sub ImportFile()
Dim TextLine
Dim drng As Range
Dim n As Integer
Dim row As Long, col As Long
Dim inde As Integer
Dim data() As String
Dim BegRow As Long, BegCol As Long
Dim index As Integer
Dim cell As Range
BegRow = 2 
BegRow = 1 
BegCol = 1
Columns("A").AutoFit
Columns("B").AutoFit
Columns("C").AutoFit
Columns("D").AutoFit
Columns("E").AutoFit
Columns("F").AutoFit
Columns("G").AutoFit
Columns("H").AutoFit
Columns("I").AutoFit
Columns("J").AutoFit
Columns("K").AutoFit
Columns("L").AutoFit
Columns("M").AutoFit
Columns("M").AutoFit
Columns("O").AutoFit
Columns("P").AutoFit
Columns("Q").AutoFit
Columns("R").AutoFit
Columns("S").AutoFit
Columns("T").AutoFit


With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Select txt file"
    .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.txt"
    .FilterIndex = 2
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show

        f = Trim(.SelectedItems.Item(1))
        Open f For Input As #1        
        Do While Not EOF(1)           
            Line Input #1, TextLine    
            TextLine = DeleteSpace(Trim(TextLine))
            data = Split(TextLine, "|")
            n = UBound(data)
            col = BegCol
            For index = 0 To n
                If IsNumeric(data(inde)) Then
                    `**Cells(row, col).Value = Val(data(index))**`
                Else
                    **Cells(row, col).Value = data(index)**
                End If
                col = col + 1
            Next  ' Index
            col = BegCol
            row = row + 1
        Loop
        Close #1    
End With
```

`End Sub`

`Function DeleteSpace(ByVal str As String) As String`
    Dim Strtemp As String

```
Strtemp = str
While Replace(Strtemp, "  ", " ") <> Strtemp
    Strtemp = Replace(Strtemp, "  ", " ")
Wend
DeleteSpace = Strtemp
```

`End Function`

`

Comment: Did you initialize `row` value? Also, Use `Columns("A:T").AutoFit` instead of individual columns

Comment: `A)` Where are you initializing the value of Row and Col `B)` Also "IsNumeric(data(inde))"? Missing an "X" in "Inde"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**row** has not been assign a value prior to its use.  There may be other errors.